# How will I get the number of the users input?

Tags: java

```
int number = 0, min = 0, max = 0, sum = 0, i = 0;
double average;
boolean notNull = true;

while (notNull == true)
{
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    number = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());

    if (number < 0)
        notNull = false;
    else
    {
        if (number>max)
            max = number;

        if (number<=max)
            min = number;

        sum += number;
        i++;
    }
}

average = (sum/i);

System.out.println("Max: " + max);
System.out.println("Min: " + min);
System.out.println("Average: " + average);
```

If i have number 15, 19, 4, 8, 12, -5

I have to output the maximum number which is 19

the minimum number is 4 because -5 is not the minimum number, it is the trigger to stop the program so therefore it is not included... however instead of 4, i get the minimum value of 12..

Comment: Please step through in your debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistakenly used `max` in place of `min` during comparison.

```
if (number <= max)
    min = number;
```

replace it with this

```
if (number <= min)
    min = number;
```

And another mistake was that - you have initialized `min` with `0`, which is itself
a minimum natural number. Instead use :

```
min = Integer.MAX_VALUE
```